# RadioButton, кнопка справа от текста

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Собственно пытаюсь сделать нормальный radioButton с кнопкой справа от текста, но не выходит. Api 23.

```xml
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="end">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="sdf"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="sdfsdf"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="sdfsdf"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

android:gravity="right" не помогает.
Вычитал совет убрать стандартную кнопку button="@null" и нарисовать справа drawableRight="drawable/btn_radio"
Но тогда теряется Material Design.

Пробовал сделать radioButton без текста, прижать его к правому краю, а левее сделать textView. Выглядит нормально, но срабатывает только при нажатии на сам radioButton.
Есть ли возможность реализовать это без потери функционала/дизайна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте для отображения кнопки изображение из [стилей библиотеки](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml#L375) `AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton` для сохранения вида Material Design:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableRight="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:text="sdf"/>
```